# Would anyone like to view my command line hangman game?

Tags: game, rust

Id like feedback on my code.  Specifically the parts where i use graphemes. I use cloned strings because the grapheme functions eat my strings.  But feel free to comment about anything else that looks like it could be improved.

https://github.com/MonkeyToiletLadder/Hangman

Dictionary

```
pub mod prelude {
    use std::io::prelude::*;
    use std::fs::File;
    use rand::prelude::*;

    pub struct Dictionary {
        pub data: Vec<String>,
    }
    impl Dictionary {
        pub fn load(&mut self, filename: &str) -> std::io::Result<()> {
            if self.data.len() > 0 {
                self.data.clear()
            }
            let mut file = File::open(filename)?;
            let mut string = String::new();
            file.read_to_string(&mut string)?;
            let split = string.split("\n");
            let vector: Vec<&str> = split.collect();
            //Only add if the first line is not empty string
            if vector[0] != "" {
                for item in vector {
                    self.data.push(item.to_string());
                }
            }
            Ok(())
        }
        pub fn get_random_word(&self) -> String {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let index = rng.gen_range(0,self.data.len());
            self.data.get(index).unwrap().to_string()
        }
        pub fn new() -> Dictionary {
            Dictionary { data: vec![] }
        }
        pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
            self.data.is_empty()
        }
    }
}
```

Main

````
use std::io;

//TODO: Make a drawing guessing game!

mod dictionary;
use dictionary::prelude::*;
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation as US;

const ENGLISH_DIR: &str = "res/dictionaries/english/";
const JAPANESE_DIR: &str = "res/dictionaries/japanese/";
const SPANISH_DIR: &str = "res/dictionaries/spanish/";
const FRENCH_DIR: &str = "res/dictionaries/french/";

#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum GameState {
    Running,
    Stopped,
}

fn main() {
    let dictionary = match std::env::args().nth(1) {
        Some(arg) => arg,
        None => "default.txt".to_string(),
    };

    let language = match std::env::args().nth(2) {
        Some(arg) => arg,
        None => "english".to_string(),
    };

    let directory = match language.as_str() {
        "english" => ENGLISH_DIR.to_string(),
        "japanese" => JAPANESE_DIR.to_string(),
        "spanish" => SPANISH_DIR.to_string(),
        "french" => FRENCH_DIR.to_string(),
        _ => {
            //Interpret language as a directory!
            language
        }
    };

    let mut d = Dictionary::new();
    d.load(&format!("{}{}", directory, dictionary))
        .expect("Could not find file!");
    if d.is_empty() {
        panic!("File {} is empty!", dictionary);
    }
    let mut  word_to_guess = d.get_random_word();

    let mut guess = String::new();

    //Fill the guess with underscores to start.
    {
        let __word_to_guess = word_to_guess.clone();
        let graphemes = 
        US::graphemes(__word_to_guess.as_str(), true)
            .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        for _ in &graphemes {
            guess.push('_');
        }
    }

    println!("Enter \"quit\" to exit the progam.");
    let mut guesses = 12;
    let mut state = GameState::Running;
    while state != GameState::Stopped {
        println!("{}", guess);
        println!("Enter a character to guess. Guesses left {}.", guesses);

        let mut input = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("Failed to read input!");

        input = input.trim().to_string();

        if input.len() > 1 {
            match input.as_str() {
                "quit" => state = GameState::Stopped,
                _ => continue,
            }
        }
        //Converting a string into graphemes takes ownership of the string.
        //So to circumvent this I cloned the strings into seperate variables.
        //Im not sure if this is going againt rust guidlines at what is best,
        //but it works.
        //This blocks only purpose is to mark the code as questionable, nothing else.
        {
            let __word_to_guess = word_to_guess.clone();
            let __guess = guess.clone();
            let mut graphemes_i =
            US::graphemes(__word_to_guess.as_str(), true)
                .collect::<Vec<&str>>();

            let mut graphemes_j =
            US::graphemes(__guess.as_str(), true)
                .collect::<Vec<&str>>();

            let mut index = graphemes_i.iter().position(|&x| x == input);

            if index.is_none() {
                guesses -= 1;
            }

            while let Some(i) = index {
                graphemes_j[i] = &input;
                graphemes_i[i] = "_";
                index = graphemes_i.iter().position(|&x| x == input);
            }

            guess.clear();

            for string in &graphemes_j {
                guess.push_str(*string);
            }
        }
        if guesses <= 0 {
            println!("The word was {}.", word_to_guess);
            state = GameState::Stopped;
        }
        if guess == word_to_guess {
            println!("You guessed the word!");
            state = GameState::Stopped;
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Most hangman games assume input is only `[A-Z]`. In languages with accents, it would be pretty difficult if you treated accented letters as different.

Comment: So i should just drop the graphemes entirely?

Comment: @dylan that depends on what you are trying to get out of this. I'm assuming this is a learning exercise, so you might want to explore that even though it wouldn't necessarily be how you'd do it it if you were making a commercial product!

Comment: The grapheme function doesn't take ownership of your strings, so the cloning is unnecessary. Perhaps it might help to show us the code that didn't work that you solved by introducing the cloned.

Comment: FYI: I updated my answer with some more comments about `main.rs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Program design

### Handling of grapheme clusters

The program operates on Unicode grapheme clusters, presumably to
handle different languages.

However, Hangman only really works on languages with an alphabet small
enough.  Japanese, as a counterexample, is written with a wide range
of individual characters — around 50 *hiragana*, 50 *katakana*,
2,136 commonly used *kanji*, and at least thousands more of uncommon
ones.  Languages that require grapheme clusters probably have an even
larger alphabet.

Therefore, I suggest dropping support for grapheme clusters, and
operate on characters instead, to simplify the code.

### Dictionary interface

It is easier to let the user enter the path to the dictionary file
directly, defaulting to, say, `./resource/default_dictionary`.  This
simplifies the argument handling.

---

## Code

### Formatting

`cargo fmt` automatically formats your code according to the standard
Rust style.  I would also suggest adding blank lines between items.

### `cargo clippy`

Running `clippy` shows several self-explanatory warnings:

```
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src\main.rs:48:9
   |
48 |     let mut word_to_guess = d.get_random_word();
   |         ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

warning: length comparison to zero
  --> src\dictionary.rs:11:16
   |
11 |             if self.data.len() > 0 {
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: using `!is_empty` is clearer and more explicit: `!self.data.is_empty()`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::len_zero)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#len_zero

warning: single-character string constant used as pattern
  --> src\dictionary.rs:17:38
   |
17 |             let split = string.split("\n");
   |                                      ^^^^ help: try using a `char` instead: `'\n'`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::single_char_pattern)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#single_char_pattern

warning: crate `HangMan2` should have a snake case name
  |
  = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default
  = help: convert the identifier to snake case: `hang_man2`

warning: 4 warnings emitted
```

### Naming

Names starting with underscores are conventionally reserved for
intentionally unused variables, as the compiler does not warn about
them.  Using such names for normal variables hides potential bugs that
can be found by the compiler.

Note that Rust allows you to reuse names via shadowing:

```
let word_to_guess = word_to_guess.clone();
```

This is useful when the new variable cannot be meaningfully given a
distinct name.

`graphemes_i` and `graphemes_j` can be named better.

### `dictionary::prelude`

There is no point in wrapping the entirety of a module in a
`prelude`.  Simply remove it and use

```
use dictionary::Dictionary;
```

in `main.rs`.

### Error handling

I suggest using the [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0) crate to construct nice stack traces
and remove the error handling boilerplate.  Just add

```
anyhow = "1.0"
```

to `Cargo.toml`.

### `Dictionary`

`data` needn't be public.

Instead of first constructing an empty dictionary and then load a file
into it, it is more idiomatic to directly construct one:

```
pub fn new<P: AsRef<Path>>(filename: P) -> Result<Self> {
    let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open(filename)?);

    Ok(Dictionary {
        data: file.lines().collect::<Result<_, _>>()?,
    })
}
```

Notes:

- paths are generally passed as an `impl AsRef<Path>` by value;
- [`std::io::BufRead::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) is probably what you are looking for.

Don't reimplement [`rand::SliceRandom::choose`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.choose):

```
pub fn get_random_word(&self) -> Result<&str> {
    self.data
        .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
        .map(|word| word.as_str())
        .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("empty dictionary"))
}
```

### `derive` traits

For simple `enum`s like `GameState`, many useful traits can be
automatically implemented using `derive`:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
enum GameState {
    Running,
    Stopped,
}
```

### `unwrap_or_else`

This pattern:

```
let dictionary = match std::env::args().nth(1) {
    Some(arg) => arg,
    None => "default.txt".to_string(),
};
```

can be simplified by using [`Option::unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else):

```
let dictionary = std::env::args()
    .nth(1)
    .unwrap_or_else(|| "default.txt".to_owned());
```

### `GameState`

You do not really need `GameState` here — simply `break` out of
the `while` loop.

### `retain`

This part:

```
let mut index = graphemes_i.iter().position(|&x| x == input);

if index.is_none() {
    guesses -= 1;
}

while let Some(i) = index {
    graphemes_j[i] = &input;
    graphemes_i[i] = "_";
    index = graphemes_i.iter().position(|&x| x == input);
}
```

can be simplified by first using [`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) and then checking
the length.